# JAXB bindings for nested element with same name

Tags: binding, jaxb

I have a schema that is given to me (so I am not in position to make changes to it), and I am trying to generate the JAXB objects for it, and I get a naming conflict because of nested elements with same name.
 I created bindings.xml to avoid the naming conflict, and it is working fine when I have a two level nesting (e.g. the XPath is something like this:

```
/A/Value/B/Value
```

So something like this solves the problem:

```
<jaxb:bindings
     node="/xsd:schema/xsd:complexType[@name='A']
        /xsd:complexType/xsd:sequence/xsd:element[@name='Value']
        /xsd:complexType/xsd:sequence/xsd:element[@name='B']
        /xsd:complexType/xsd:sequence/xsd:element[@name='Value']">
        <jaxb:class name="InnerValue" />
   </jaxb:bindings>
```

But now I have a three level nesting like this:

```
/A/Value/B/Value/C/Value
```

and I don't know how to define the bindings (whether I need two of them ) to avoid compilation errors.

Any help much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to customize your complex types, not elements. So attach your bindings to the corresponding `xs:complexType`s. And yes, you will probably need two of them for inner `B` and `C` classes. I'd name them `A_B` and `A_B_C`, something like that.

See also [`jaxb:globalBindings/@localScoping='topLevel'`](https://jaxb.java.net/nonav/2.0/binding-customization/http.java.sun.com.xml.n/element/globalbindings.html#attr_localScoping), might be useful.